# Why my iPhone app rejected?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

Following the reason for reject:

> 17.1: Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to
>   information about how and where the data will be used
>   ----- 17.1 -----
>
> We found your app does not obtain user consent before collecting the
>   user's personal data, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, the app accesses user's iPad contacts without
>   permission.
>
> To collect personal data with your app, you must make it clear to the
>   user that their personal data will be uploaded to your server and you
>   must obtain the user's consent before the data is uploaded.
>
> iOS 8 includes keys for specifying the reason the app will access the
>   user's protected data. When the access prompt is displayed, the
>   purpose specified in these keys is displayed in that dialog box. If
>   your application will be transmitting protected user data, the usage
>   string in your access request should clearly inform the user that
>   their data will be uploaded to your server if they consent.
>
> For more information on these keys, please see the Information
>   Property List Key Reference.

Now, it's true that I am using the API (for already 4 years... nothing changed in the last update) to get contact data from the iPhone's Contacts app, however, I save this data to a local SQLite database and not sending it anywhere. Furthermore, I don't have my own server and therefore I can't send it to such server as indicated in the reject reason.

I do allow users to make a backup of their database and upload it to their own Dropbox account if they explicitly choose to do so. However, I don't believe that user's own private Dropbox account is considered to the developer's server.

Did anyone encounter this rejection?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple review - You should refer your query to the App Store support team

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal    -  Use that

Comment: I don't agree. The issue could be related to an API usage, so other users encountering the same issue might benefit from the answer. But the link however is very useful, thanks!

Comment: Do you ask the user for permission to even save this to your local SQL database? It doesn't matter whether its sending it to a server or just saving it locally you still need the users permission to do it.

Comment: The iPhone OS is automatically requesting the user permission to do so on the first try. This is not up to the developer. The developer can only add a specific message if the usage is not straightforward (which is not my case).

Answer (score 6):

Have you requested user permission to read his contacts in **plist**, with a message describing your request?

> iOS 8 includes keys for specifying the reason the app will access the
>   user's protected data. When the access prompt is displayed, the
>   purpose specified in these keys is displayed in that dialog box

if not add the following key in your **plist** with an appropriate message (**NSContactsUsageDescription**). Check here for more detail:

one more thing that every messaging app upload contacts to their servers without any problem.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/reference/infoplistkeyreference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW14

check this too section **"Allows the user to control access to their contacts data"** :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Concepts/WhatsInAB.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001021-BAJGJJAH

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The iPhone OS is automatically requesting the user's permission to access his/her Contacts on the first try. I think that Apple rejected my app because they think I am uploading the contact info to my own server and such a privacy-related action requires a dedicated message in NSContactsUsageDescription key. 
Are you sure that an app accessing the user's Contacts must provide a message in the NSContactsUsageDescription key regardless of the usage?

Comment: Yes you are right but ios8 requests you to put a clear message for the reason you ask for a permission ,check this "iOS 8 includes keys for specifying the reason the app will access the user's protected data."

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, NSContactsUsageDescription is supported since iOS 6.0 and not iOS 8.0. I also looked up for "iOS 8 includes keys for specifying the reason the app will access the user's protected data." and found only this post... :) Would you mind sending me a URL or any reference about iOS 8.0 specific privacy considerations ?

Comment: I have edit the answer, There is no clear resource about this but in IOS8 Apple applied many privacy restrictions.